# Csv-файлы, Python

Tags: python, csv

У меня есть **csv**-файл (более 1000 строк) со следующими данными:

```
popolvivod,type,username,date,amount
1,visa,Ivan,15.06,300
0,paypal,Victor,12.03,500
1,qiwi,Misha,13.07,604
```

Мне нужно выполнить следующие задания:

1. Посчитать статистические показатели:

- медиана,
- мода,
- средняя,
- минимум,
- максимум.

2. Создать новый столбец, в котором разместить разницу между
   максимумом и минимумом.
3. Разбить данные на несколько блоков (не менее 3, приблизительно равных
   по размеру) по некоторому критерию (критерий определить
   самостоятельно).
4. Привести круговую диаграмму для проделанного разбиения.
5. В зависимости от особенностей набора данных для каждого блока
   построить график (гистограмму, ...).
6. Сгруппировать данные (GroupBy) по некоторому признаку и сохранить
   результаты в новые таблицы. Для каждой новой таблицы провести
   сортировку по сложному ключу, состоящему из нескольких признаков.
   Для каждой таблицы своя сортировка.

Вот мой код:

```
def csv_dict_reader(file_obj):
    c=0
    reader = csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
       print(f'4) {c+=line["amount"]} % .')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("../input/ratafa/dannie.csv") as f_obj:
        csv_dict_reader(f_obj)
```

Но когда я, например, хочу посчитать общую сумму 300+500+604, то выводит ошибку. В чем проблема?

Comment: Может проще сразу `Pandas` использовать или у вас задание именно с модулем `csv` работать?

Comment: А так то тут конечно бред `print(f'4) {c+=line["amount"]} % .')` вы не можете одновременно и считать данные и выводить. Делайте это по очереди - отдельно добавляйте, отдельно выводите.

Comment: можете пример кода привести, нужно использовать данные из csv

Comment: Для начала https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/02_read_write.html